# Deploy jetty module on client with puppet

Tags: jetty, puppet

I want to try to install the following module on my clients using puppet.

https://forge.puppetlabs.com/maestrodev/jetty

So I install the module on my master using:

```
puppet module install maestrodev-jetty
```

this seems to have worked

```
$ puppet module list
/home/puppetmaster/.puppet/modules
├── maestrodev-jetty (v1.1.2)
├── maestrodev-wget (v1.5.6)
└── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.3.2)
```

What I want to do next is deploy jetty, set it up and deploy it on my clients.
I made the following manifest for this:

```
class { 'jetty':
          version => "9.0.4.v20130625",
          home    => "/opt",
          user    => "jetty",
          group   => "jetty",
        }


        exec { 'stanbol-war-download':
            command     => "wget -0 /opt/jetty/webapps/my.war http://some.url/my.war",
            path        => "/usr/bin/",
            creates     => "/opt/jetty/webapps/my.war",
          } ->
          exec { 'jetty_start':
            command => "java -jar /opt/jetty/my.jar jetty.port=8181 -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512M",
            cwd     => "/opt/jetty",
            path    => "/usr/bin/",
            notify  => Service["jetty"],
            returns => [0, 254],
        }
```

I have been trying for a while but I can't seem to get it installed and running on my clients without getting any sort of error, syntax or otherwise.